# Cannot stop IIS Express asking to authenticate me on my local Silverlight application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, authentication, silverlight, iis-express

**Edit:** *I do not need any patronising replies about how Silverlight is almost out of date. Of course I know this. When you work in software support for a company (a) you don't get to use a time machine to change choices made years ago and (b) you often have to support systems that aren't the latest because "just replace it" isn't necessarily possible. Yes this system is being phased out. If it is purely Silverlight that is reacting to a change from WebDev to IIS Express then please cite references to that effect.*

I seem to have a very specific problem with my laptop that colleagues don't experience. When I run our Silverlight UI solution locally at the latest version I am always asked to sign in. However, my user credentials (the same ones I use to sign into my laptop) are always rejected.

The difference is that in the latest solution we are now invoking IIS Express.

Previously the solutions ran like this (via a launch batch file - I'm unclear what has altered within the solution) **and if I return to using this form I am able to avoid the authentication**

```
start webdev.webserver40.exe /port:{port number} /path:"%CD%\{application folder}"
```

whereas with IIS Express we are using this:

```
start iisexpress.exe /config:"%CD%\{solution folder}\.vs\config\applicationhost.config" /site:{site name as shown in applicationhost.config}
```

I've looked through the applicationhost.config file:

I've altered this at the end

```
<location path="{site path}">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

The security block looks fine:

```
           <access sslFlags="None" />
           <applicationDependencies>
                <application name="Active Server Pages" groupId="ASP" />
            </applicationDependencies>
           <authentication>
               <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />
               <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
               <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />
               <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
               <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false">
                </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
               <windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
                    <providers>
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
           </authentication>
           <authorization>
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
            </authorization>
           <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true" />
```

to my untrained eye.

Finally I even updated the csproj.user file

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>false</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

use IIS Express was false and Windows was enabled and anonymous disabled.

but these settings were also true in the old code.

I'm really baffled as to what can be set on my machine.

Note: Windows 10, VS 2015.

Comment: Why are you using Silverlight? It's not just that it was discontinued *several* years ago and even finding the SDK is difficult (deliberately, to stop people from creating new apps). The only browser that could run it, IE, was removed from Windows 10

Comment: As for what's going on, IIS settings *in production* are configured using IIS manager.  Production sites don't use IIS Express, they use IIS. A site's settings can be overriden through settings in `web.config`, not `applicationhost.config`. `ApplicationHost.config` affects all sites on a server

Comment: You only get a month before Silverlight's end of life, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/silverlight-end-of-support-0a3be3c7-bead-e203-2dfd-74f0a64f1788 So whatever troubleshooting can be a waste of time. But if you do want to learn more about IIS Express settings, try Jexus Manager https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file which might help you launch IIS Express without VS. That check can tell whether the issue is caused by VS or not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is a specific applicationhost.config in use that can be seen when running IIS Express via the system tray icon, so I know it is using this particular one - it's inside the solution under the .vs system folder. The web.config settings aren't changing between WebDev and IIS Express.

Comment: What *are* the settings? Besides, if Windows Authentication works the server won't ask you for credentials *if IE is configured correctly* to use Windows Auth in this specific zone. That's the whole point of using Windows Authentication. By default only sites in the `Trusted` and maybe `Intranet` zone can do that

Comment: As for `I do not need any patronising replies` it's not patronising. This isn't a `yes but in an ideal world` situation. Silverlight is over 10 years in the past. Finding any information is hard as googling returns mainly guides for migrating away from it. There are no books about it and even the people that did use it when it was mainstream will have a hard time to remember its quirks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is patronising to assume the lowest level of knowledge of someone asking a technical question, yes. Sure, if you want to put it as a note in a postscript to an answer that's fine but to slam your first comment as, effectively, "You have no idea what you're doing and haven't read anything," is simply not helpful, nor similar from Lex Li.

(Also factually incorrect as IE is inside Windows 10 since I'm using it to use Silverlight.)